# Use leaflet map as filter in shiny app

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny

Is it possible to use a leaflet map to filter data in a shiny app (like one can in, e.g., Tableau or Power BI) by clicking on, e.g., a state on the map, and then another graph or table gets filtered based on the selection?

Comment: You can have a look at [that app](https://hleviel.shinyapps.io/dashboard/), which is using plotly instead of leaflet (take a while to load on shinyapps be patient)

Comment: Yes, it's possible

Comment: Please, try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post a sample of your data or create an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), and show us what you already tried.

Comment: Crosstalk (http://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/index.html) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: This is great. Two good references. Thanks.

Comment: We plan to add this type functionality in `mapedit`.  See [post](http://r-spatial.org/r/2017/01/30/mapedit_intro.html) or more specifically [mapedit select](http://r-spatial.org/r/2017/01/30/mapedit_intro.html#selecting-regions).