# Click on points in a leaflet map as input for a plot in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

Using the example below, I am trying to figure out a way to add functionality to my shiny app such that the following works:

1. Click on a point on the map
2. This changes the plot according to station AND
3. Inputs the corresponding station into the "Click on Station" sidebar

Basically I'd like to be able either click on the map for a station OR input the station manually with a keyboard.

Is this possible with leaflet? I've seen references to using plotly which may be ultimate solution but I'd love to leaflet if possible in no small part because I have already done a lot of work with leaflet. This is similar to this[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41858870/use-leaflet-map-as-filter-in-shiny-app) though there is working example here:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data("quakes")
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(title = "Station Lookup",
                     dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
                     dashboardSidebar(
                       sidebarMenu(
                         menuItem("Data Dashboard", tabName = "datavis", icon = icon("dashboard")),
                         menuItem("Select by station number", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
                                  selectizeInput("stations", "Click on Station", choices = levels(factor(quakes$stations)), selected = 10, multiple = TRUE)
                         )
                       )
                     ),
                     dashboardBody(
                       tabItems(
                         tabItem(tabName = "datavis",
                                 h4("Map and Plot"),
                                 fluidRow(box(width= 4,  leafletOutput("map")),
                                          box(width = 8, plotOutput("plot")))
                         )
                       )
                     )
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    ## Sub data     
    quakes_sub <- reactive({

      quakes[quakes$stations %in% input$stations,]

    })  

    output$plot <- renderPlot({

      ggplot(quakes_sub(), aes(x = depth, y = mag))+
        geom_point()

    })


    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet(quakes) %>% 
        addTiles() %>%
        addCircleMarkers(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, layerId = ~stations, color = "blue", radius = 3) %>%
        addCircles(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, weight = 1,
                   radius = 1, label = ~stations, 
                   popup = ~paste(stations, "<br>",
                                  depth, "<br>",
                                  mag)
        )

    })

  }
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `input$map_marker_click` and `updateSelectInput()`:

Edit: Added functionality that stations can be deleted from `selectInput()` as suggested by OP in the comments.

(Dont forget to add `session` to your sever function).

```
observeEvent(input$stations,{
  updateSelectInput(session, "stations", "Click on Station", 
                    choices = levels(factor(quakes$stations)), 
                    selected = c(input$stations))
})

observeEvent(input$map_marker_click, {
  click <- input$map_marker_click
  station <- quakes[which(quakes$lat == click$lat & quakes$long == click$lng), ]$stations
  updateSelectInput(session, "stations", "Click on Station", 
                    choices = levels(factor(quakes$stations)), 
                    selected = c(input$stations, station))
})
```

However, this functionality is partly overwritten by the popup event(?). As i see it there is an inner blue circle (darker blue) that if clicked produces the popup. However, the `input$map_marker_click` only works if you click the outer (light blue) circle. I would report it as a bug,...

Comment: Only issue with this approach is that the last `click` persists in the select input - as in you can clear it. It stay there until a new `station` is clicked in which case you can manually backspace it from the "Click on Station" field. Changing `selected = c(input$stations, station)` to `selected = c(station)` fixes that issue though I'm totally sure why.

Comment: Also are you suggesting you will report it and I should... happy either way.

Comment: ah didnt see that issue, let me take a look. Concerning the reporting, go ahead, as i dont require the functionality for the moment and wouldnt wait fot the updates,...

Comment: And of course changing `selected` means that you can't click on multiple stations at once.

Comment: Concerning your last comment, i dont really understand how clicking multiple markers would work. And i cant see it in your question to be honest,... Concerning the "deleting", that makes sense it is required. I made an edit, it will work now.

Comment: So valuable answer

Comment: very glad to hear that @CarlosVecina.

Comment: Works great after adding adding `session` to `server <- function(input, output, session)`. Thank you!